# SPWeb.GetItems Does not Retun Folder Type items

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, contenttype, spweb

I retrieved all items in my SharePoint list using `.GetItems()` command.

However, it does not have contain `folder type` items in my result.

A type of `ERMS Folder Content Type` do exists in the list, as below:

[image]

Documents of other content types are still being displayed, no issues.

May I know if I have used the incorrect commands to retrieve folders in a SharePoint list?

---

Below is my code snippet:

```
$baseUrl = "http://test.com"
$web = Get-SPWeb($baseUrl)

$RDlistUrl  = $baseUrl + "/RecordsDocument"  
$RDlist = $web.GetList($RDlistUrl)
$RDitems = $RDlist.GetItems()

foreach ($RDitem in $RDitems)
{
    if ($RDitem.ContentType.Name.Contains("Folder"))
    {
       //no output captured.
    }
```

Comment: Documents can't be folder Content type . if you have folders in library then Only Folder Content type you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splist.GetItems()` would not get folder items. You have to use `splist.folders` to get folder items : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms443958(v=office.14)

Please change your code to this:

```
#Get folder items
$RDitems = $RDlist.Folders

foreach ($RDitem in $RDitems)
{
    if ($RDitem.ContentType.Name.Contains("Folder"))
    {
       $RDitem
    }
}
```